# equivalent of omega() in jeet?

Tags: css, grid, stylus, jeet-grid

using jeet.gs i have two classes taking up one half each of the total width of their parent container.

something like this (stylus notation):

```
.wrapper
  .alpha
  .beta
    col(1/2)
```

now, when i write some jade like this:

```
.wrapper
  .alpha
    p Number 1
  .beta
    p Number 2
  .alpha
    p Number 3
```

then the row doesnt wrap properly: "Number 1" ends up on one row, "Number 2" and "Number 3" end up the second row.

I would like "Number 1" and "Number 2" on the first row, and "Number 3" on the second row.

why is this happening? do i need to clearfix? Is there something like omega() as in susy and neat? is there any other way to offset?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clearfix .wrapper.

If you're using nib you can use this:

```
.wrapper
   clearfix()
```

Otherwise you'll want to make your own mixin and use it.

```
clearfix()
   zoom 1
   &:before,&:after
      content ""
      display table
   &:after
      clear both
```